# Regex Help, Search for function names and return them

Tags: c#, regex

Need a regex here that will take a file line by line and output all of the function names. So for example:

```
    function apples_and_bananas ($params, $arguments) {
       print "hello world of yellow and red";
    }
```

And return apples_and_bananas

Using regex so that it runs fast when doing line by line string manipulation.
Unless there is a better way of doing this. 
I don't know how to generate regex it is so complicated and I was never taught it, can you also point to a good document to learn?
This is for c# in a windows form app.

Comment: What language is the code that you are searching written in?

Comment: The language is C# in a windows form

Comment: @coolestdude: Specify that in your question.

Comment: right edit made, I should have but was a scatter brain about it thanks user Dor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the page ["Constants" @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), the regex should be:
`function\s+([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\s*\(`

This regex supposed to be correct for almost every language.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using PHP, and want to use PHP for the code to find function names you can use this code. If you're using a different language the code should be fairly similar. Just need to read the file in, and match it against the regex expression `/function\s+(\w*)\s*\(/`:

```
$filename = 'yourfile.php';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/function\s+(\w*)\s*\(/', file_get_contents($filename), $matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
// Matches contains array of function names
```

I've tested this for you.

Comment: Sweet php this is not relevant to this question (sorry edited with the correct language) but it works and gets the job done I am up voting for those that want to see it in php as it is a language I regularly use. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

The captured string form the regex below should be the function name.

```
/^function\s+([^\s]+)\s/
```

You should be able to google for regex tutorials to learn how they work. You can also check out [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570).

Comment: Thanks but the book is no longer available. There might be an updated one out if you have this bookmarked.

Comment: It should be available on Amazon through a reseller or ebay.

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely do everything you need:

```
/function\s+([^\s\(]+)/
```

However, if you want to restrict the names of functions to only those acceptable in PHP, you need the longer regex @Dor suggested.