# preg_match - get numeric value from a function

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, web-scraping

I am trying to get the value from `transaction` function.

Example:

```
$response = "transaction(12346675); $('#Tracking').html('<script> random random  random</script>');";
```

I want to get `12346675` value. How can that be done?

I have tried `preg_match('/([\w\_\d]+)\(([\w\W]*)\)/', $response, $match);` but it dont seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: Will the function name always be `transaction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^transaction\((\d+)\)/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Generalized patterns:

- `^\s*\w+\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)`
- If function name is a PHP identifier:
  `^\s*[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)`

For similar question, see: [Regex Help, Search for function names and return them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820376/regex-help-search-for-function-names-and-return-them/6820517#6820517)

Answer (score 0):

```
reg_match('/\D+\((\d+)\)\.*/', $response, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the number after the first word, provided it is enclosed in parentheses:

```
preg_match('/\w+\((\d+)\)/', $response, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the first number of the line, then there's no need to complicate it with the second half of your expression:

```
preg_match('/(\d+)/', $response, $match);
```

This is a simple match for the first number found on your line.